# Aplicação PHP offline e online

Tags: php, mysql

Queria saber se é possível e, caso for, quais tecnologias eu posso usar para criar uma aplicação que rode offline e quando o usuario tiver conexao com a net, os dados sejam levado para o servidor (hospedagem) automaticamente?

Comment: você pode utilizar o sqlite do navegador para armazenar e depois enviar os dados armazenado caso esteja online para o server

Comment: Mesmo fechando o navegador os dados ainda ficaram salvos?

Comment: sim cara, ele salva na "memória" do navegador, seria como um banco de dados interno do navegador

Comment: Saquei. Vlw, Marcos!

Comment: vou te dar um exemplo, perae, mas em javascript

Comment: É inviável responder pois há diversas formas de resolver e não há como determinar qual técnica é mais adequada para o seu caso específico. Para determinar é preciso fazer uma análise completa do seu projeto e ainda assim pode haver conflitos de opiniões sobre o que é mais adequado ou não. Resumindo, tema amplo demais e baseado em opiniões.

Comment: Apesar de uma dúvida interessante, o site é pra perguntas e respostas objetivas, e sua questão é mais adequadar pra troca de opiniões e discussão, que fogem do nosso formato. Aqui tem umas dicas das perguntas que funcionam bem no nosso formato: [Ask], [Que tipo de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](/help/dont-ask), [Sobre quais tópicos posso perguntar](/help/on-topic) e [Help].

Answer (score 0):

O **sqlite** segue o mesmo principio do **mysql**, como você utiliza o **php**, segue um exemplo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/sqlite.setup.php, no seu caso você faria um `if` verificando se há conectividade, partindo desta idéia há duas formas de trilhar esta requisição:

- Setando no sqlite quando estiver offline e quando ocorrer a conexão ele enviar para o servidor.
- Ou, você seta tudo offline e apenas quando quiser ou por definição do usuário realiza a sincronização.

Mais sobre o Sqlite: http://www.devmedia.com.br/sqlite-o-pequeno-notavel/7249.

Comment: Vlw, cara. Vou já tentar implementar!

Comment: que isso cara, fico feliz por ajudar

Answer (score 0):

## Sumário

É inviável responder pois há diversas formas de resolver e não há como determinar qual técnica é mais adequada para o seu caso específico. Para determinar é preciso fazer uma análise completa do seu projeto e ainda assim pode haver conflitos de opiniões sobre o que é mais adequado ou não. Resumindo, tema amplo demais e baseado em opiniões

## Yes! We Can!

Mas se quer mesmo saber se é possível, sim, é possível.

É possível rodar a aplicação em PHP offline na máquina local do cliente e ter o mesmo aplicativo online num servidor. Pode inclusive instalar MySQL no cliente. Enfim, o próprio cliente seria ao mesmo tempo o servidor para a versão offline.

Talvez o ponto mais crítico é fazer a sincronização entre os dados offline e os dados online.

Se o aplicativo for exclusivo para um único cliente (um único computador), isso não será um problema, mas se existir mais de 1 cliente, a coisa complica pois deve ter maior cuidado em relação a chaves duplicadas, etc.

Mesmo que seja apenas 1 cliente, deve-se tomar esse cuidado.

## Caso de estudo

Outro exemplo é, caso haja mais de um usuário, suponha que um desses fez um delete num registro e sincronizou. No dia seguinte o outro usuário que está offline precisa desse registro. No PC dele o registro ainda existe então ele faz as firulas que precisa fazer e sincroniza. Aí começa a dar pau em tudo porque o outro usuário havia excluído no dia anterior.

Lidar com chaves únicas é fácil. Mas como pode ver, nesse pequeno exemplo de exclusão a coisa começa a complicar.

## Conclusão

Por isso, repito o que citei acima, sem analisar o projeto completo não há como lhe indicar de forma adequada o que pode ser melhor aplicado.

O ponto chave de tudo isso é a logística. Pense na logística e no projeto em si para determinar o que pode ser viável.

Answer (score -1):

O PHP é uma linguagem server-side, ou seja, você precisa enviar dados para o servidor, que retornará uma resposta. Logo o PHP não pode ser executado numa máquina sem que um serviço web esteja rodando.

No minimo seria necessário ter um apache, nginx ou localhost(wamp/xammp/lamp) rodando em cada máquina que pretenda usar o seus site em offline, ele precisaria ficar inteiramente armazenado no cache do navegador. Você precisaria armazenar dados em cookies, etc...

Possível até é, mas pode ser inviável dependendo do tipo de serviço que você pretende oferecer

Comment: Não fui eu quem deu o negativo, mas isso aqui ta errado: "Logo o PHP não pode ser executado numa máquina sem que um serviço web esteja rodando.". O PHP pode ser rodado normalmente como executável sem nada de web ou browser envolvido.